# WSUS clients missing from WSUS server database

Tags: windows, updates

I have a set of workstations set to use WSUS rather than windows update. Most update fine, however, in few cases, whilst client machines appear to contact the WSUS server fine, and download/apply updates, the WSUS summary does not list these IPs as ever having contacted the server.

As an example, one affected client machine shows, in windowsUpdate.log:

2017-06-03  15:57:27:352    1084     a8     Report  Uploading 2 events using cached cookie, reporting URL = http:///ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx

2017-06-03  15:57:27:367    1084     a8     Report  Reporter successfully uploaded 2 events.

However, the wsus_server in question shows no record of this client IP having contacted it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - it looked like this was the solution:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sus/2009/05/05/resolving-the-duplicate-susclientid-issue-or-why-dont-all-my-clients-show-up-in-the-wsus-console/

It fitted the symptoms perfectly...but on trial, the solution proposed didn't do the job...

Next idea?